# Question about biased estimator

Tags: statistics

Assume $X$ is a random variable from a population with normal distribution. Using the likelihood function I get the expression below: 
$$\hat{\sigma}_X^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(X_i-\mu)^2} n$$
for variance.

I want prove that, $\operatorname{E}[\hat{\sigma}_X^2]=\frac{n-1} n \sigma_X^2$.

I begin ...

$$\operatorname{E}\left[\hat{\sigma}_X^2\right]=\dfrac 1 n \operatorname{E} \left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2\right]$$

$$\frac 1 n \left( \operatorname{E}\left[(X_1-\mu)^2\right] + \operatorname{E}\left[(X_2-\mu)^2\right] + \cdots + \operatorname{E} \left[ \left( X_n-\mu \right)^2 \right]\right)$$

pdta: $\mu$ is a theorical mean (not estimator of mean)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by pdta, but $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is an estimator $\hat{\mu}$ for the mean, not the actual mean $\mu_X$.

Comment: I think he knows that Robert.  It is just that he is using non-standard notation.

Comment: I edit my question $\mu$ is a theorical mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: expand out $(X_i - \mu)^2 = X_i^2 - 2 X_i \mu + \mu^2$.  Now compute $E[X_i^2]$, $E[X_i \mu]$ and $E[\mu^2]$.

EDIT: If $\mu$ is the actual mean rather than an estimator, then the statement is wrong: $E[(X_i - \mu)^2] = \sigma^2$ and $E[\hat{\sigma}_X^2] = \sigma^2$.

Comment: yes ... $E[X_i^2]$-$2\mu E[X_i]$ + $\mu^2 E[1]$ ... other step please ...

Comment: I edit my question $\mu$ is a theorical mean

Comment: I don't see that this answer contributes anything.  If the question is how to find the expected value of the given random variable, the straightforward way is this: $$\operatorname{E} \left( \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2 \right) = \frac 1 n \operatorname{E} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2 = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{E}((X_i-\mu)^2) = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^2 = \frac 1 n n\sigma^2 = \sigma^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X)^2]&= \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i -\bar X]^2\\
&=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n E[ (X_i -\bar X) (X_i -\bar X)]\\
&= \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i (X_i -\bar X)]- \bar X\sum_{i=1}^n  \space E[(X_i -\bar X)]\\
&= \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i (X_i- \bar X)]\\
&= \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n E[{X_i}^2]- E[\bar X \space X_i] \\
&=\frac1n\left( \sum_{i=1}^n E[{X_i}^2]- \   E\left[\ \bar X \space\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]\right)\\
&=\frac1n\left( \sum_{i=1}^n E[{X_i}^2]- n E\left[ \bar X \space\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i}
{n}\right]\right) \\
&=\frac1n\left( \sum_{i=1}^n E[{X_i}^2]- n E\left[ \bar X^2\right]\right) \\
&=\frac1n\left(n \sigma^2_x + n {\mu}^2- n \left[ \frac{\sigma^2_x}{n}+\mu^2\right] \right)\\
&=\frac{n-1}{n} \sigma^2_x\\
\end{align}

Note:

1. $E[X^2]=\sigma^2 + \mu^2$
2. $E[\bar X]=\mu$
3. $\sigma^2_\bar x= \frac{\sigma^2_x}{n}$

Comment: +1 Can you give some reference of explain the contents of the Note?

Comment: 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Comment: 1. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance which explains variance calculation in terms of expectation.
2. see https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/167
3.  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance in "Sum of uncorrelated variables" section.